# How to display recycler view items side by side

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How can we display `RecyclerView` items side by side. i tried to do this by using `FlowLayoutManager` and `FlexboxLayoutManager` but it is showing in list format only here is the code with `FlowLayoutManager`:

```
  FlowLayoutManager flowLayoutManager = new FlowLayoutManager();
  flowLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
    listView.setLayoutManager(flowLayoutManager);

    madapter = new testingAdapter(Quran_e_Kareem.this,surah1);
    listView.setAdapter(madapter);
```

here is the code with FlexboxLayoutManager:

```
    FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    //         Set flex direction.
    flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
    flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
    flexboxLayoutManager.setAlignItems(AlignItems.FLEX_START);
    flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_START);
    listView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);

madapter = new testingAdapter(Quran_e_Kareem.this,surah1);
listView.setAdapter(madapter);
```

I am getting result list this

[image]

But i want to get this way

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just take a textview , append the strings and set it to textview , if you dont want to perform click on the string , if your requirement is to show the string in that manner , i would suggest you to use textview and set text on it

Comment: https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#choice-chips

Comment: @Quick learner is write.. you no need to use recyclerview, take one textview under scrollivew and using for loop append data to textview. that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ChipsLayoutManager 
use following lib helps me to do same

```
 implementation 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
```

Answer (score 1):

set orientation of linearlayoutmanager for recyclerview

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity,RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
setFlexDirection as Row Reverse
```

Comment: I tried row_reverse also but no change still showing in list format only

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code and make your adapter textview wrap content may it will solve your problem.

```
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.flex_box_recycler_view);

        // Create the FlexboxLayoutMananger, only flexbox library version 0.3.0 or higher support.
        FlexboxLayoutManager flexboxLayoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Set flex direction.
        flexboxLayoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);

        // Set JustifyContent.
        flexboxLayoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.SPACE_AROUND);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(flexboxLayoutManager);
```

Add into xml like this:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:flexWrap="wrap"
    app:alignItems="stretch"
    app:alignContent="stretch" >
```